# Transfer parameters between Groovy scripts in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a `Groovy` script, it is present as a test step. I need to pass a parameter value, a variable from it to another `Groovy` script, which is in a script assertion, in a `SOAP` request. These are executed after each other. `Property Transfer` step is unable to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this statement in **Script Assertion** of Request

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("Prop","testing")
```

So here you are setting a testcase Property.

Now you can use that property in **Groovy Script**

```
def val=context.expand('${#TestCase#Prop}')
log.info val
```

So the value stored in Property Prop in Script Assertion is used in Groovy Script